# jquery keyup not working while extracting text from input fields

Tags: jquery

I want to create two textboxes and a textarea that concatenates the texts from both input fields.
My html code is as follows:

```
<input class= 'inpo' type='text'/>
<input class= 'inpo' type='text'/>
<textarea id='res' readonly></textarea>
```

My jquery code is as follows:

```
$(".inpo").keyup(function(){
        var str = "";
    $(".inpo").each(function() {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    })
    $("#res").val(str);
});
```

However, it does not work. I do not get anything on my console either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use val() not text():

```
$(".inpo").keyup(function(){
        var str = "";
    $(".inpo").each(function() {
        str += $(this).val() + " ";
    })
    $("#res").val(str);
});
```